how to minus values in certain rows and within every panel in a dataset
The data is:
   df <- structure(list(country = c("Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland", "Poland","Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain"), Code = c("POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "POL", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "PRT", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP", "ESP"), year = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954,1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955), IV = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -18L))

I want to substract IV values for the year of 1955 from 1952; 1954-1951; 1953-1950. And so for every country. In the outcome dataset (let's name it 'newdata'), the new variable "newIV" has to show this difference; values for 1950, 1951 and 1952 years should be deleted as this:

Poland's 'newIV' value for 1955 is the difference between its IV values for the years of 1955 and 1952. Poland's 'newIV' value for 1954 is the difference between its IV values for the years of 1954 and 1951. Poland's 'newIV' value for 1953 is the difference between its IV values for the years of 1953 and 1950.
Guys, do you think you could provide me with the code that would do this automatically?
I hope the question is not confusing.

Are these absolute values? You mentioned you want to subtract IV values from 1955 from the other years. In Poland 1953, 3-2 = 1. In Portugal 1953, 1-2 = -1 yet the result in the image says 1. Could you clarify?

sorry I didn't get you.  'newIV' is the difference of IV value for the year of 1955 and1952; 1954 minus 1951; 1953 minus 1950. And so for every country. I just need the code that would do this automatically.

When the year is 1955, why is the value of newIV changed? 1955 - 1955 = 0

for IV value for Poland for the year of 1955 is 3, and for the year of 1952 is 1. So the difference is 2.

I apologize if the question is unclear on that part. I will try to edit the question and clarify it

There is no 1952 in the results, as you mention it is deleted

You could merge an aggregated subset to get a temporary IV_temp column, that you can subtract and remove, finally subset with desired years.
> merge(df, 
+       aggregate(cbind(IV_temp=IV) ~ Code, subset(df, year == 1950), I), all=TRUE,
+       sort=FALSE
+ ) |> transform(IV=IV - IV_temp, IV_temp=NULL) |> subset(!year %in% 1950:1952 )
   Code  country year IV
4   POL   Poland 1953  1
5   POL   Poland 1954  2
6   POL   Poland 1955  2
10  PRT Portugal 1953  1
11  PRT Portugal 1954  1
12  PRT Portugal 1955  0
16  ESP    Spain 1953  2
17  ESP    Spain 1954  3
18  ESP    Spain 1955  4

Not sure which year you want to subtract, I used 1950 which looks similar to your desired output.
